# How to remove multiple slashes in URI with 'PREG'

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I am using `str_replace()` for removing extra slashes from url i dont know how to redirect the url to new url if find multi slashes in url?

```
if(str_replace(':/','://', trim(preg_replace('/\/+/', '/', PERMALINK), '/')))
{
  echo 'Yes found multi slashes redirect it to new url';
}
else
{
  echo 'Not found multi slashes';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the plus symbol + in regex means the occurrence of one or more of the previous character. So we can add it in a preg_replace to replace the occurrence of one or more / by just one of them

$url =  "site.com/edition/new///";

$newUrl = preg_replace('/(/+)/','/',$url);

// now it should be replace with the correct single forward slash
echo $newUrl

Comment: Ok, but how to check if multiple slashes in the URL then redirect it to a new URL?